# How to differentiate google home device from others

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api

i'm working on an app that uses multiple google home devices with the same account. I would like to map the google home device to a certain room but can find a unique id for each devices. Dialogflow has originalRequest.data.device before but now its already gone.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to uniquely identify one device that a user owns.